# Track KeyPresses & Modifier Keys when window is minimized and log into a file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

I am Trying to Create an Windows Form Application which tracks every Keypresses and Then log into a file

I could create an windows form application which could log into a file if it was in focus. but When i tried to use it minimized then nothing is logged.

this form application should understand multiple modifiers key and log them accrodingly. Suppose an User Presses Ctrl + Enter in the browser then it should be able to log like {ctrl} + {enter}. It should log every keypresses like Escape, backslashes. it also should know whether the keypress is lower or uppercase.

Comment: I have browsed many posts have similar criteria in it but didnot find what i m actually looking for. so i realized that i needed another question. if you find that any other questions may solve my issue. please guide me, i would be delighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for `low level keyboard hooks`. There is plenty of example code for it already, even in c#. So just google it.